# how to display space according to datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I had written program which copy data into txt file program is given below

```
declare
empsfile utl_file.file_type;
cursor empscur is
select * from newemp;
begin
empsfile := utl_file.fopen('DIPRJDIR','EMPS.TXT','W');
for rec in empscur
loop
utl_file.put_line(empsfile,rec.EMPNO||rec.ENAME||rec.JOB||rec.MGR||rec.HIREDATE||rec.SAL||rec.COMM||rec.DEPTNO);
end loop;
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(empsfile );
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ERROR -->' ||  SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

output of the above progarm is

```
7839KING      PRESIDENT017-NOV-815000010
7698BLAKE     MANAGER  783901-MAY-812850.5.530
7782CLARK     MANAGER  783909-JUN-812450010
7566JONES     MANAGER  783902-APR-812975020
7654MARTIN    SALESMAN 769828-SEP-811250140030
7499ALLEN     SALESMAN 769820-FEB-81160030030
7844TURNER    SALESMAN 769808-SEP-811500030
7900JAMES     CLERK    769803-DEC-81950030
7521WARD      SALESMAN 769822-FEB-81125050030
7902FORD      ANALYST  756603-DEC-813000020
7369SMITH     CLERK    790217-DEC-80800020
7788SCOTT     ANALYST  756609-DEC-823000020
7876ADAMS     CLERK    778812-JAN-831100020
7934MILLER    CLERK    778223-JAN-821300010
```

Now my problem  is I want display space according to data type of above field for example suppose ENAME   VARCHAR2(10) than if name in data is 6 field than i have to display 4 blank space please help me in this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can LPAD function help you?

```
utl_file.put_line(empsfile,rec.EMPNO||LPAD(rec.ENAME,10,' ')||rec.JOB||rec.MGR||rec.HIREDATE||rec.SAL||rec.COMM||rec.DEPTNO);
```